# Perl - longest common prefix of 2 or more strings?

Tags: perl

How can i create a Perl subroutine which would take in an array and find the longest common prefix for 2 or more of its elements? (strings)

I have this code:

```
sub longest_common_prefix {
    $prefix = shift;
    for (@_) {
        chop $prefix while (! /^\Q$prefix\E/);
        }
    return $prefix;
}
```

But it only works if you are looking for the longest common prefix of **all** strings.

For example, if i pass an array with the following strings:

```
aaaBGFB
aaaJJJJ
jjfkBBB
aaaHGHG
```

I want it to return `aaa` as the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if "j12345" is in the mix? What if we added "bbbb1" and "bbbb2"? Is it looking for the longest prefix between any two strings? Or is it the LCP for strings that have at least 1 in common?

Comment: The latter, yes, sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: It could be anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to store the information in a hash. In this example, I set the hash key to the length of each prefix, and the value being the actual prefix found.

Note that this method overwrites a key and value if a same-length prefix exists, so you'll always get the *last* prefix found of the longest length (`sort()` takes care of finding the longest one).

The regex says "find the first character in the string and capture it, and use that char found in a second capture, and capture as many as there are". This string is then `join()`ed into a scalar and put into the hash.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %prefixes;

while (<DATA>){
    my $prefix = join '', /^(.)(\1+)/;
    $prefixes{length $prefix} = $prefix; 
}

my $longest = (sort {$b <=> $a} keys %prefixes)[0];
print "$prefixes{$longest}\n";

__DATA__
aaBGFB
aaaJJJJ
jjfkBBB
aaaHGHG
```

Output:

```
aaa
```

Comment: Fails for `qw( abcd abce xxy xxz )`. (Prints `xx` instead of `abc`.)

Comment: This only works for prefixes that are runs of the same letters. If you had `(aaBGFB, aaaJJJJ, interspecies, interstellar)` for example, the longest common prefix is `inter`

Answer (score 5):

I'd use a modified [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Normally, one could use the following to add to a trie:

```
sub add {
    my $p = \shift;
    my $s = shift;
    $p = \( $$p->{$_} ) for split(//, $s);
    $$p->{''} = 1;
}
```

But we need two modifications:

- All prefixes of a string must be added when adding a string. For example, adding `abc` should also add `a` and `ab` to the trie.
- When adding to the trie, we want to return the length of previously-existing part of the path taken.

So we need:

```
sub add {
    my $p = \shift;
    my $s = shift;

    my $cp_len = 0;
    for (split(//, $s)) {
       $p = \( $$p->{$_} );
       ++$cp_len if $$p->{$_}{''};
       $$p->{''} = 1;
    }

    return $cp_len;
}
```

Combine (an optimized version of) this with an algorithm to find the longest strings in a list and with an algorithm to remove duplicate strings from a list to get the following solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

sub add {
    my $p = \shift;
    my $s = shift;

    my $cp_len = 0;
    for (split(//, $s)) {
       ++$cp_len if exists($$p->{$_});
       $p = \( $$p->{$_} );
    }

    return $cp_len;
}

my $t;
my $lcp_len = 0;  # lcp = longest common prefix
my %lcps;
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my $cp_len = add($t, $_)
      or next;

   if ($cp_len >= $lcp_len) {
      if ($cp_len > $lcp_len) {
         $lcp_len = $cp_len;
         %lcps = ();
      }

      $lcps{ substr($_, 0, $cp_len) } = 1;
   }
}

my @lcps = sort keys %lcps;

if (@lcps) {
   say "Longest common prefix(es): @lcps";
} else {
   say "No common prefix";
}
```

Data:

```
abc
abc
abcd
abcde
hijklx
hijkly
mnopqx
mnopqy
```

Output:

```
Longest common prefix(es): hijkl mnopq
```

The time taken by the above is proportional to the number of input characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a hash of an array of words keyed by the first character. By definition, if you have words starting with the same letter, those words share at least a one character common prefix of that one letter. Then reduce to the single longest prefix by stepping through the hash by character:

```
use strict; use warnings;
sub lcp {
    (join("\0", @_) =~ /^ ([^\0]*) [^\0]* (?:\0 \1 [^\0]*)* $/sx)[0];
}

my %HoA;
my $longest='';

while (my $line=<DATA>){
    $line =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g ;
    push @{ $HoA{substr $line, 0, 1} }, $line if $line=~/^[a-zA-Z]/;
}

for my $key ( sort (keys %HoA )) {
    if (scalar @{ $HoA{$key} } > 1){
        my $lon=lcp(@{ $HoA{$key} });
        my $s = join ', ', map { qq/"$_"/ } @{ $HoA{$key} };
        print "lcp: \"$lon\" for ($s)\n";
        if (length($lon) > length($longest)) {
            $longest=$lon;
        }            
    }
    else{
        print "$key: no common prefix\n";
    }
}
print "\nlongest common prefix is \"$longest\"\n";

__DATA__
aardvark
aaaBGFB
aaaJJJJ
jjfkBBB
aaaHGHG
interspecies
interstellar
interstate
```

Prints:

```
lcp: "aa" for ("aardvark", "aaaBGFB", "aaaJJJJ", "aaaHGHG")
lcp: "inters" for ("interspecies", "interstellar", "interstate")
j: no common prefix

longest common prefix is "inters"
```